# PHP Segment multidimensional array into smaller arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

What im trying to do is create a function that convert this array

```
{
    "data": {
        "churnStructured": [
            {
                "id_region": "4",
                "iso": "be",
                "mcc": "206",
                "country": "Belgium",
                "carriers": [
                    {
                        "carrier": "Triton PCS",
                        "id_carrier": 68,
                        "brands": []
                    },
                    {
                        "carrier": "Beeline",
                        "id_carrier": 80,
                        "brands": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id_region": "4",
                "iso": "bg",
                "mcc": "284",
                "country": "Bulgaria",
                "carriers": [
                    {
                        "carrier": "Comium",
                        "id_carrier": 75,
                        "brands": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

into smaller arrays, like this:

```
{[
    "first_array" : [{
        "id_region": "4",
            "iso": "be",
            "mcc": "206",
            "country": "Belgium",
            "carriers": [
                {
                    "carrier": "Triton PCS",
                    "id_carrier": 68,
                    "brands": []
                },
                {
                    "carrier": "Beeline",
                    "id_carrier": 80,
                    "brands": []
                }
            ]
    ]},
    "second_array": [{
        "id_region": "4",
        "iso": "bg",
        "mcc": "284",
        "country": "Bulgaria",
        "carriers": [{
                "carrier": "Comium",
                "id_carrier": 75,
                "brands": []
                }]
    }],
    "third_array": [{}],
    "n_array": [{}]
]}
```

as you can see the new arrays has as the first branch, their country, and the structure is the same for their children.

I was thinking into do a recursive function, that get each value and with that validate with the keys, however, i don't know how to do the proper iteration and get each country as a new array with their respective children.

and also the array is dynamic, it can receive an array of n-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a numerical array, not `first_array` etc. This should do the trick:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$data = $data['data']['churnStructured'];

$results = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $results[] = $y;
}

var_dump($results);
```

Which you can see in action here! https://3v4l.org/V6VoO

Comment: im gonna try, your solution :)

Comment: glad i could help